# Why is katakana used for the onomatopoeia/sounds in the background?

Tags: japanese-language

In Japanese, katakana is used for loan words/foreign words, but it shows up a lot in backgrounds of manga as what seems to be onomatopoeia. Is this manga-specific, and where did it originate?

[image]

The center white katakana on the bottom panel seem to be "fuaaaaa", for instance.

Comment: You would probably get better answers by asking this on http://japanese.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the Japanese language (which already has a SE), not something specific to anime/manga.

Answer (score 1):

Using onomatopoeia to stress sound effects in literature is not manga-specific or even comic-specific. For example, 1966's *Batman* TV series or even Nickelodeon's *The Fairly OddParents* had readily available audio to match their onscreen text with emphasis. But several cultures have their own origins. Tracing back **when** this particular artistic/literary device caught on would be pretty exhaustive, if even credible at all.